# How to display information when option changes?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a drop down menu below:

```
<select name="session" id="sessionsDrop">
<option value="">Please Select</option>
<option value='20'>EWYGC - 10-01-2013 - 09:00</option>
<option value='22'>WDFRK - 11-01-2013 - 10:05</option>
<option value='23'>XJJVS - 12-01-2013 - 10:00</option>
<option value='21'>YANLO - 11-01-2013 - 09:00</option>
<option value='24'>YTMVB - 12-01-2013 - 03:00</option>
</select> </p>
```

Below I have a Multiple Select box where it displays a list of students that is taking the select assessment from the drop down menu above:

```
$studentactive = 1;

$currentstudentqry = "
SELECT
ss.SessionId, st.StudentId, st.StudentAlias, st.StudentForename, st.StudentSurname
FROM
Student_Session ss 
INNER JOIN
Student st ON ss.StudentId = st.StudentId
WHERE
(ss.SessionId = ? and st.Active = ?)
ORDER BY st.StudentAlias
";

$currentstudentstmt=$mysqli->prepare($currentassessmentqry);
// You only need to call bind_param once
$currentstudentstmt->bind_param("ii",$sessionsdrop, $stuentactive);
// get result and assign variables (prefix with db)

$currentstudentstmt->execute(); 

$currentstudentstmt->bind_result($dbSessionId,$dbStudentId,$dbStudentAlias,$dbStudentForename.$dbStudentSurname);

$currentstudentstmt->store_result();

$studentnum = $currentstudentstmt->num_rows();   

$studentSELECT = '<select name="studenttextarea" id="studentselect" size="6">'.PHP_EOL;      

if($studentnum == 0){

$studentSELECT .= "<option disabled='disabled' class='red' value=''>No Students currently in this Assessment</option>"; 


}else{   

while ( $currentstudentstmt->fetch() ) {

$studentSELECT .= sprintf("<option disabled='disabled' value='%s'>%s - %s s</option>", $dbStudentId, $dbStudentAlias, $dbStudentForename, $dbStudentSurname) . PHP_EOL; 
}

}

$studentSELECT .= '</select>';
```

But I have a little problem, I need a way to be able to display the list of students in the select box when the user has selected an option from the drop down menu. The problem with the php code is that the page has to be submitted to find its results.

My question is that is there a way that javascript/jQuery can be combined so that the php code above can look for the students that takes the chosen assessments but be able to use javascript/jQuery to display the student information in the select box when assessment is chosen in drop down menu?

Comment: the keyword is ajax. It is pretty straight forward what you are trying to do. Question is, what have you tried on this regard?

Comment: @itachi I have done ajax, I have tried just php but when I realised I had this problem. I tried bit of jquery but got deeply stuck. But the answer below will hopefully help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a php Ajax solution so you can update the list of students will be refreshed without the need to refresh the page

```
$('#sessionsDrop').change(function() {
  var search_val=$(this).val(); 
  $.post("./nameofyourphp.php", {search_term : search_val}, function(data){
   if (data.length>0){ 
     $("#divtodisplaydata").html(data); 
   } 
  }) 
 })
```

and add this to you php so you can get the selected value

```
$term = $_POST['search_term'];
```

and here is step by step tutorial

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-php-jquery-ajax/index.html

Comment: Can I quickly ask before I go through tutorial, does the post in ajax suppose to go on a sperate page and I put php in sepearte page or do you want me to post it to same page?

Comment: separate files like in example