# Where to place code in order to display details from a query result

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, mysqli

I am having big trouble in knowing which code is suppose to be placed in which pages.

What I am trying to do is the following:

- In `addstudentsession.php` page, User selects an assessment from the `#sessionsDrop` drop down menu
- Everytime an assessment is selected from the drop down menu (or in other words everytime an option is changed in the drop down menu), it will perform an ajax call to a seperate page `addedstudents.php` to perform a query to see which students are in the chosen assessment.
- The students that are taking the assessments from the result of the query should be displayed in the a multi select box  in the `addstudentsession.php` (If the user has not selected an assessment, I still want a blank multi select box to be displayed in `addstudentsession.php`

My question where should the placement of each code should be to be able to perform this because I am not getting this right at all. No Multi Select box is appearing at all and I am getting an undefined variable on this.

Below is the current `addstudentsession.php` page:

**Drop down menu:**

```
$sessionHTML = '';

if($sessionnum ==0){
$pHTML = "<span style='color: red'>Sorry, You have No Assessments under this Module</span>";
} 

$sessionHTML = '<select name="session" id="sessionsDrop">'.PHP_EOL;
$sessionHTML .= '<option value="">Please Select</option>'.PHP_EOL;           

$studentInfo = array();

while ( $sessionqrystmt->fetch() ) {

$sessionHTML .= sprintf("<option value='%s'>%s - %s - %s</option>", $dbSessionId, $dbSessionName, date("d-m-Y",strtotime($dbSessionDate)), date("H:i",strtotime($dbSessionTime))) . PHP_EOL;    

}


$sessionHTML .= '</select>';

...

<form action='".htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])."' method='post' id='assessmentForm'>
<p><strong>Assessments:</strong> {$sessionHTML} </p>   
</form>";
```

Multi Select Box:

```
//getting undefined error below of studentSELECT
     $moduleexist="
        <form id='moduleExistForm'>
        <p><strong>Current Students in Chosen Assessment:</strong></p>
        <p>{$studentSELECT}</p>
        </form> 
        </div>";

        echo $moduleexist;
```

**Ajax Call:**

```
        $('#sessionsDrop').change( function(){
            var search_val = $(this).val();
            $.post("addedstudents.php", 
            {studenttextarea : search_val}, 
            function(data){
   if (data.length>0){ 
     $("#studentselect").html(data); 
   }
)};
```

Below is the current `addedstudents.php` page where it performs the query and lists the details in the select box:

```
<?php

$studentactive = 1;

$currentstudentqry = "
SELECT
ss.SessionId, st.StudentId, st.StudentAlias, st.StudentForename, st.StudentSurname
FROM
Student_Session ss 
INNER JOIN
Student st ON ss.StudentId = st.StudentId
WHERE
(ss.SessionId = ? and st.Active = ?)
ORDER BY st.StudentAlias
";

$currentstudentstmt=$mysqli->prepare($currentassessmentqry);
// You only need to call bind_param once
$currentstudentstmt->bind_param("ii",$sessionsdrop, $stuentactive);
// get result and assign variables (prefix with db)

$currentstudentstmt->execute(); 

$currentstudentstmt->bind_result($dbSessionId,$dbStudentId,$dbStudentAlias,$dbStudentForename.$dbStudentSurname);

$currentstudentstmt->store_result();

$studentnum = $currentstudentstmt->num_rows();   


$term = $_POST['studenttextarea'];


$studentSELECT = '<select name="studenttextarea" id="studentselect" size="6">'.PHP_EOL;      

if($studentnum == 0){

$studentSELECT .= "<option disabled='disabled' class='red' value=''>No Students currently in this Assessment</option>"; 


}else{   

while ( $currentstudentstmt->fetch() ) {

$studentSELECT .= sprintf("<option disabled='disabled' value='%s'>%s - %s s</option>", $dbStudentId, $dbStudentAlias, $dbStudentForename, $dbStudentSurname) . PHP_EOL; 
}

}

$studentSELECT .= '</select>';

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `addedstudents.php` you must return the value `$studentSELECT`. Add an

```
echo $studentSELECT
```

at the end of your PHP.

You also never use `$term = $_POST['studenttextarea'];` anywhere in your PHP code. Furthermore `$sessionsdrop` is nowhere defined and `$stuentactive` is probably a typo (`$studentactive`). Same goes for `$currentstudentqry` vs `$currentassessmentqry`.

Comment: Like I said i am really messing this up :) I am trying to follow the answer to this SO question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14209271/how-to-display-information-when-option-changes) but I am not gettign it right at all

Comment: @user1881090 Then start with echoing some fixed string in addedstudents.php, to see whether ajax works. Then go forward from there and fix the other problems one by one.

Comment: Will do, thanks for your help :) bad mistakes on the typos, sorry bout that, I need to take more care

Comment: When you are in chrome (for instance), right clicking on the page and clicking inspect element then going to console can help you debug javascript errors

Comment: @OlafDietsche Managed to fix the page and got it working, thanks again

Comment: @user1881090 Congratulation :-)